# Remove grouping variable for data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to use `data.table` to do some wrangling and would like my resulting data table to *not* include the grouping variable.

Here's a MWE:

```
library("data.table")
DT <- data.table(x = 1:10, grp = rep(1:2,5))
DT[, .(mmm = mean(x)), by = grp]
```

This produces:

```
   grp mmm
1:   1   5
2:   2   6
```

which is all fine. However, I'd prefer the `grp` not to be here. This can be fixed by chaining the `data.table` calls and setting `grp := NULL` or just throwing the variable away, but can I prevent it in the first call so I only return `mmm`?

Comment: An alternative to `DT[, .(mmm = mean(x)), by = grp][, grp := NULL][]` could be `DT[, .(mmm = DT[, .(mmm = mean(x)), by = grp]$mmm)]`

Comment: What exactly don't you like about `DT[..., by = grp][, !'grp']` or `DT[..., by = grp][, grp := NULL]`?

Comment: I'm working on a remote system with limited resources and hit the roof with memory every now and then. My understanding (and it could be wrong) was that chaining the data table still keep everything after the first call and the memory is first freed after setting `[, grp := NULL]` so was hoping to save that initial step. It's not that I don't agree that `[, grp := NULL]` is more aesthetically and functionally pleasing

Comment: @ekstroem there is no way I can think of to use `by`, and not use up that extra column of memory (and I also have a hard time imagining that column being the choking point). I haven't checked, but maybe `tapply` would use less memory for this particular case (but you'll pay a stiff performance penalty).

Comment: @eddi You are probably right. I was just in cut-away-all-that-doesn't-matter-mode and thought there would be a way for me to skip including the by variable in my call altogether. The time penalty of `tapply` makes that a path I don't think I can pursue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't clear why you don't want to use this. Using `DT[, .(mmm = mean(x)), by = grp][, grp := NULL][]` would be my first choice.

Although I won't advise it, you can also use:

```
DT[, .(mmm = DT[, .(mmm = mean(x)), by = grp]$mmm)]
```

which will give you the desired result as well:

> ```
>    mmm
> 1:   5
> 2:   6
> ```

Although you will get the same result, it is better not to use this method. The major drawback of this is that you will make your code unnecessary complicated when you want to summarise more than value column. You would then get something like:

```
DT[, .(mx = DT[, .(mx = mean(x)), by = grp]$mx, my = DT[, .(my = mean(y)), by = grp]$my)]
```

while using the normal *data.table-way* would be:

```
DT[, .(mx = mean(x), my = mean(y)), by = grp][, grp := NULL][]
```

To conclude:

Using the `DT[, .(mmm = mean(x)), by = grp][, grp := NULL][]` method would thus be your best choice.

Comment: Doing this makes about as much sense as scratching your right ear with your left foot. And what exactly are you going to do when your `i-expression` is more than one column..

Comment: @eddi Why the downvote? As I said in my first sentence, using `DT[, .(mmm = mean(x)), by = grp][, grp := NULL][]` would be my first choice. the alternative I offered works (although it is not the preferred way of doing this). Updated the answer.

Comment: @Jaap because I think that this answer is not useful - it's not generalizable, it's bad grammar (typing the same thing many times over), and it serves no functional purpose; and reiterating something mentioned in the OP doesn't make it useful to me. I understand the effort, but see no value added here.

Comment: @eddi I agree that it is better not to use this method. I've updated my answer a second time to better illustrate that. Explaining that it is better not to do something seems pretty usefull to me.