# Rename grouping variable in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to group a `data.table` but use a different name for the grouping variable in the final output.

#### Data

```r
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
d <- data.table(grp = sample(4, 100, TRUE))
```

#### Options

I can use chaining like this:

```r
d[, .(Frequency = .N), keyby = grp][
  , .("My Fancy Group Name" = grp, Frequency)]
#    My Fancy Group Name Frequency
# 1:                   1        27
# 2:                   2        31
# 3:                   3        22
# 4:                   4        20
```

or rename the column before:

```r
d[, c("My Fancy Group Name" = list(grp), .SD)][
  , .(Frequency = .N), keyby = "My Fancy Group Name"]
#    My Fancy Group Name Frequency
# 1:                   1        27
# 2:                   2        31
# 3:                   3        22
# 4:                   4        20
```

or define an alias for the grouping variable and remove the grouping variable afterwards:

```r
d[, .("My Fancy Group Name" = grp, Frequency = .N), keyby = grp][
  , grp := NULL][]
#    My Fancy Group Name Frequency
# 1:                   1        27
# 2:                   2        31
# 3:                   3        22
# 4:                   4        20
```

but all forms use a chain.

I can avoid the chaining by [the not recommended approach from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47497386/remove-grouping-variable-for-data-table) (which is not only a hack, but very inefficient on top):

```
d[, .("My Fancy Group Name" = .SD[, .N, keyby = grp]$grp,
      Frequency = .SD[, .N, keyby = grp]$N)]
#    My Fancy Group Name Frequency
# 1:                   1        27
# 2:                   2        31
# 3:                   3        22
# 4:                   4        20
```

#### Questions

Conceptually I would like to use something like this

```r
# d[, .(Frequency = .N), keyby = c("My Fancy Group Name" = grp)]
```

1. Is it possible to achieve the solution chain free not using the hack I showed?
2. Which option performs "best" in terms of memory/time if we have a huge `data.table`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually do similar to your attempt but use `list` instead of `c` :

```
library(data.table)
d[, .(Frequency = .N), keyby = list(`My Fancy Group Name` = grp)]
#Also works with quotes
#d[, .(Frequency = .N), keyby = list("My Fancy Group Name" = grp)]

#   My Fancy Group Name Frequency
#1:                   1        27
#2:                   2        31
#3:                   3        22
#4:                   4        20
```

Shorter version :

```
d[, .(Frequency = .N), .("My Fancy Group Name" = grp)]
```

Comment: Et voila. When the solution is so close and yet so far. +1

Answer (score 1):

Using `setnames()` should also be efficient:

```
setnames(d[, .N, keyby = grp], c("My Fancy Group Name", "Frequency"))
```